# cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm new in android, I have been trying to open a Android project but I don't know how that was configured. I have tried this:

1. Installed Java 16 and 17
2. Downloaded Android studio Hedgehog (Lasted version)
3. This is `build.gradle` module
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uslN.png)
4. This is the `build.gradle` Project
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy99A.png)

Would you mind give me any idea how to run this app?
Thank you